# Subshell didn't have a new process id?

Tags: bash

In my shell scripts,I wrote those:

```
#! /bin/bash
(ls;echo$$)
echo$$
```

then I run the shell,the two output is the same

```
2592
2592
```

why subshell didn't have a new process id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$$` is the process ID of the main shell.  To get the process ID of a subshell, use BASHPID:

```
$ echo $$ $BASHPID; ( echo $$ $BASHPID; )
19610 19610
19610 21937
```

The subshell has PID 21937.

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> BASHPID
>   Expands to the process ID of the current bash process.  This differs from $$ under certain  circumstances,  such  as  sub‐
>   shells that do not require bash to be re-initialized.

By contrast, `$$` is documented as follows:

> `$$`
>   Expands to the process ID of the shell.  In a () subshell, it expands
>   to the process ID of the current shell, not the sub‐ shell.